# NSPredicate for fetching keywords that are in a string

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

In core data I have an entity called keyword with a property 'text'. I want to find all keyword objects that are contained in a particular sting.

I tried:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains[c] text", myString];
```

But that crashes. It seems like if it will only work if it's reversed.

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you want? Are you looking for all Keyword entities `k` for which `k.text contains myString`, or all entities for which `k.myString contains text`, where myString is a variable attribute name on Keyword?

Comment: The opposite, i'm looking for all Keyword entities in which k.text (are contained) in mystring. Also it should be noted that keywords are potentially longer than a single word, so they are more like key-phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate works on the entity, so you have your predicate reversed. Since your entity's text property contains a single word, you'd split the string into multiple words and then test:

```
// This is very simple and only meant to illustrate the property, you should
// use a proper regex to divide your string and you should probably then fold
// and denormalize the components, etc.
NSSet* wordsInString = [NSSet setWithArray:[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
NSPredicate* pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.text IN %@", wordsInString];
```

Comment: What if I want to match more than just a single word from the target phrase? For instance, my keyword.text is "root beer" and I want it to match when compared to "Goose Island Root Beer". Can I split both sides of the expression and check to see if both parts of the keyword are in the wordsInString set?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing in reverse direction.

Try this.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"text contains[cd] %@", myString];
```